# Which Database can be use on android, web and as well as windows smoothly?

Tags: android, web-apps, database, c#, remote-desktop

I am looking for a database which can be use smoothly on android apps, web applications and windows as well. I am working on C# winForms projects and i want to run my desktop application and android app and web on same database smoothly without any issues. is there any server which is compatible for all type of platforms?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. For example: What does it have to do with remote-desktop (your tag)? What amount of data are you speaking about (for up to several MB, the embedded SQLite database would be fine)? Where shall the database run (on-device, remote server on what OS)?

Comment: I am sure that there are many. Sqlite is the first that springs to mind

Comment: If sqlite one of thos where i replace the database to access it by all applications?

Comment: Sqlite keeps its database as a single file, so you could copy it around

Comment: But i want to access single database from multiple platforms like android,  web and deaktop applications, and want to use same data